# Custom Implementation ForEach - Java

Tags: java, java-8

I got the following code from java JDK Interface Iterable File

```
public interface Iterable<T> {
    Iterator<T> iterator();

    default void forEach(Consumer<? super T> var1) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(var1);
        Iterator var2 = this.iterator();

        while(var2.hasNext()) {
            Object var3 = var2.next();
            var1.accept(var3);
        }

    }

    default Spliterator<T> spliterator() {
        return Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(this.iterator(), 0);
    }
}
```

I Got This piece code from Iterable.class - JDK 8

```
Object var3 = var2.next();
```

In the above line get Object from var2 Then

`var1.accept(var3);` was called Now var1.accept only accept the value of "T" But This Code They Pass Object Data type So How it's Works?

Comment: Never call a variable "var3" or "var". Never.

Comment: @Taschi He used a decompiler.

Comment: Doesn't make it less bad.

Comment: Why are you recreating `Iterable`? Many classes will provide you with an `Iterable` object. Your motivation is probably uninformed or unwise.

Comment: It's not my piece of code i copied this from Iterable.class - it's inside in the Java JDK. I Just copy the code and rerun the code.

Comment: are you really understand my question. please read out once again. I asking this piece of code is written by java co not me. its works on JDK internally but when  i copy paste this it's not working

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you're trying to accomplish by rewriting the code; probably you're thinking this means you can 'cast' objects to your ForEach type which is not how java works.

Your `var2` is a raw type; don't do that. It needs to be `Iterator<X>` where X is something appopriate.

a `Consumer<? super T>` can accept a `T` and nothing else. THerefore, `var3` needs to be of type `T`. It is of type `Object`, which is why this code does not compile.

`var2` could be an `Iterator<T>`, at which point `var3` can be a `T` at which point this will all work fine.

Comment: I'm trying to learn how internally works. the thing is i got the piece of code from java jdk recompiled one. So my question is simply i use the same code got from de - compiler it's works on JDK but why its not works on my IDE. I really know its a cast issue i cannot assign Object to "T"  i already mentioned that in my question. So i need to now how it's works on java internally

Comment: There is no need to use a decompiler for this stuff - java is open source. The decompiler messed up is all you need to know - and all decompilers do this - that kind of generics info is no longer present in the class file, so a decompiler can't know.